# how to show data from Json file in correct way with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I need to get the data from a json file below(please click the "Json File" link to see how is that structure of Json file) but i am confused what should I put after "$Scope.listOfRecipe=",  I put response.data.recipes, but it doesn't work here and there are some error .

> `angular.js:12520 TypeError: Cannot read property 'recipes' of undefined
>       at recipesController.js:10
>       at angular.js:10296
>       at angular.js:14792
>       at r.$eval (angular.js:16052)
>       at r.$digest (angular.js:15870)
>       at r.$apply (angular.js:16160)
>       at g (angular.js:10589)
>       at T (angular.js:10787)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.w.onload (angular.js:10728)`

[Json File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rgj5M.png) here is my json file

This is my `recipesControllers.js`

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

 myApp.controller('namesCtrl',function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.listOfRecipe = null;

$http.get('http://164.132.196.117/chop_dev/recipe/recipes.json')
     .success(function (response) {
         $scope.listOfRecipe = response.data.recipes;
     })

});
```

This is my `Index.html`

```
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">
</script>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="x in listOfRecipe ">
        {{ x.Recipe.id + ', ' + x.Recipe.name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script src="C:/Users/Enetfirm  Server/Desktop/AngularJs/recipesController.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your error message indicates that `response.data` does not exist.  Have you checked the contents of `response` to see if it contains what you expect it to?

Comment: You should be able to do `response.recipes`. If not, can you put a `console.log(response)` ? Open the browser console and see if you are getting any response from the server.

Comment: `response.data` is the pattern for receiving data inside a `.then` block, but you are trying to use it in a deprecated `.success` block.

Comment: I have tried "$scope.listOfRecipe = response.data; console.log(response);", it shows 
Object
data
:
Object
recipes
:
Array[2]
0
:
Object
BaseType
:
Object
id
:
"1"
name
:
"Beef"
__proto__
:
Object
Course
:
Object
id
:
"3"
name
:
"Lunch"
__proto__
:
Object
Difficulty
:
Object
Ethnicity
:
Object
PreparationMethod
:
Object
PreparationTime
:
Object
Recipe
:
Object
Source
:
Object
User
:
Object
__proto__
:
Object
1
:
Object
length
:
2
__proto__
:
Array[0]
__proto__
:
Object
headers
:
(d)
status
:
200
statusText

Comment: now it is working , Thanks a lot, that console.log(response) help me a lot

Comment: Great, I'm glad it's working. Also I put my comment as an answer, if my answer helped you, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `console.log(response)` and see what the response is and adjust your code accordingly.

But I would recommend using the standard promise pattern:

```
$http.get('http://164.132.196.117/chop_dev/recipe/recipes.json')
  .then(function(resp) {
    $scope.listOfRecipe = resp.data.recipes;
  })
  .catch(function(errResp) {
    // catch error
  })
  .finally(function() {
    // when it is done do something in the view
    // remove a spinner gif or scroll to top ...
  });
```

Comment: Thank u, I used console.log(response) , it help me find out where are errors and problems. "catch " and "finally" is good.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify the file is downloading on the developer tools - network tab ?

Make sure it's working, and please console.log response and response.data in order to verify its there !

It's a Json file means the response is the Json it self and not res.data

Please check it and reply for sharing your solution